# On an eigenvalue inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

Let $\lambda_1 (\cdot)$ be the larger absolute value
eigenvalue of a $2\times2$ matrix and $\lambda_2 (\cdot)$
the smaller absolute value eigenvalue of a $2\times2$ matrix, i.e.
$|\lambda_1 (\cdot)| \ge |\lambda_2 (\cdot)|$.
Is it true that 
$$\Big||\lambda_1 (A+B)|-|\lambda_1 (A)|\Big|^{1/3}+\Big||\lambda_2 (A+B)|-|\lambda_2 (A)|\Big|^{1/3}\leq|\lambda_1 (B)|^{1/3}+|\lambda_2 (B)|^{1/3}$$
for any two $2\times2$ symmetric real matrices $A$ and $B$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might give a link to the m.se question so we could easily check what's there and not duplicate work. 

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: @unknown (yahoo): my sincere apologies for misreading your new question in haste. [earlier comment now deleted] (But the restriction that $B$ be diagonal real, rather than merely real-symmetric, still seems superfluous.)

Comment: In fact, I suggest you post the new question as a *separate question*, but include a link back to this one in order to provide background context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alleged inequality is **false**, even if you restrict $A$ and $B$ to be positive definite matrices. Consider the following,

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1.2281 & 0.6361\\\\
0.6361 & 1.9690
\end{bmatrix},\quad\quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
3.7829 &-0.6021\\\\
-0.6021 & 0.4002
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then, we have the following:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda(A+B) = (5.0114, 2.3687)\\\\
\lambda(A)   = (2.3347, 0.8624)\\\\
\lambda(B)   = (3.8868, 0.2962)
\end{eqnarray*}

From, which we see that

\begin{eqnarray*}|\ \ |\lambda_1(A+B)| -|\lambda_1(A)|\ \ |^{1/3} + |\ \ |\lambda_2(A+B)|-|\lambda_2(A)|\ \ |^{1/3} & = & 2.5348\\\\
|\lambda_1(B)|^{1/3} + |\lambda_2(B)|^{1/3} &=& 2.2389
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: you're unknown, but you're welcome :-) !!